# "error: cannot find symbol" when building for Android in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I keep getting this error when trying to build for android in my flutter app. This all happened when i added `firebase messaging version 7.0.3`. Even after removing it i got this issue persisting.

```
/Users/bright/Desktop/flutter_apps/rush_user_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin());
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   class FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin                         
  location: package io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 
/Users/bright/Desktop/flutter_apps/rush_user_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapsPlugin());
                                                                    ^   
  symbol:   class GoogleMapsPlugin                                      
  location: package io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps                       
/Users/bright/Desktop/flutter_apps/rush_user_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin());
                                                                      ^ 
  symbol:   class GoogleSignInPlugin                                    
  location: package io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin                     
/Users/bright/Desktop/flutter_apps/rush_user_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin());
                                                                     ^  
  symbol:   class ImagePickerPlugin                                     
  location: package io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker                      
/Users/bright/Desktop/flutter_apps/rush_user_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
                                                                           ^
  symbol:   class SharedPreferencesPlugin                               
  location: package io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences                
5 errors  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       102.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here is my `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java`

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
 * plugins that support the Android platform.
 */
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    ShimPluginRegistry shimPluginRegistry = new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine);
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.github.ponnamkarthik.toast.fluttertoast.FlutterToastPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.baseflow.geolocator.GeolocatorPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.baseflow.googleapiavailability.GoogleApiAvailabilityPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapsPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin());
      com.codeheadlabs.libphonenumber.LibphonenumberPlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("com.codeheadlabs.libphonenumber.LibphonenumberPlugin"));
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.baseflow.location_permissions.LocationPermissionsPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.aboutyou.dart_packages.sign_in_with_apple.SignInWithApplePlugin());
  }
}
```

Here is my android folder structure

[image: Android folder screen shot]

I have tried to google for solutions but i have not found any suggestions that were similar to my issue. Here is my flutter doctor output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287 darwin-x64, locale en-KE)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Here are my dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.5.2+2
  pinput: ^0.2.6
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  dotted_border: ^1.0.6
  dotted_line: ^2.0.2
  date_field: ^1.0.5
  intl: ^0.16.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  flutter_rating_bar: ^3.2.0+1
  signature: ^3.2.0
  scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.1.9
  http: ^0.12.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  provider: null
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.2.0
  location: ^3.2.4
  geolocator: ^5.3.2+2
  shimmer: ^1.1.2
  flutter_google_places: ^0.2.6
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.19
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
  flutter_polyline_points: ^0.2.4
  uuid: null
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.4
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

I have tried migrating to a new project and transffering the lib, ios and pubspec.yaml only but the error is still there.
Please help!

Answer (score 39):

For me I always try cleaning flutter build:

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: magic command...

Answer (score 13):

After a sweaty struggle i decided to try a random solution out of the countless search results i got and voila

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case i tried

```bash
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub get
```

but with no positive results
so I went to the **app level build.gradle** file located at `android/app/build.gradle` and changed the `...SdkVersion` values:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 33  // was `flutter.compileSdkVersion`
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 29 // was `flutter.minSdkVersion`
        targetSdkVersion 33 // was `flutter.targetSdkVersion`
    }
```

Comment: yes, it worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Just run

```
flutter clean
flutter build
```

I had same problem, this one helps.

Answer (score 6):

Issue fixed for my by running following two commands

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 5):

You must have detached a plugin from file *pubspec.yml*.

The cache needs to be clear.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, this method works.

```
rm -rfv ~/.gradle/caches/build-cache-1/
```

and

```
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case

My Error: ->

```
C:\Users\Niket\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:321: error: cannot find symbol
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
```

Solution:

Step 1 : Goto android/app/src/build.gradle

Step 2 : Update compileSdkVersion to your virtual device version

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 //before its 30 
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're a star. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`flutter clean` does not remove `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java`

try to remove it manually from `android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java`

And of course `flutter pub get` after that.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all options for this

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter build apk`

Even after this i could not find my solution.
finally i ratified my mistake that i have not added

`key.properties` file in project

Answer (score 1):

I just set my java path and it works fine  Go --> File ---> Project Structure-->choose java path
all Set

Answer (score 1):

The generally accepted solution here (flutter clean + flutter pub cache repair) did not work for me.

What ended up working was the nuclear option of **deleting my entire ~/.gradle folder** and then rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

Spent an hour in random fixes. Finally running 'flutter clean' and rebuilding worked

Answer (score 0):

for me it was the problem with the targetSdkVersion as recently I had upgraded to the **Jelly Fish Canary 9** version of android studio and I was running the project of my office mate which he shared with me using zip file and my follow team member was using older version from the Jelly Fish Canary 9 version. then I changed the minSdkVersion to 34 which was the latest at the time and it solved my problem.

**Solution:  androidSdkVersion 34**