# cannot find symbol BuildConfig FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle

I updated a 2 year old flutter-project and get the following error at debugging. I need help, because no entry of google and SO helped. I try to fix the error for over one week.

the error:

> Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
> /Users/michael/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.24.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar.java:19:
> error: cannot find symbol
> LibraryVersionComponent.create(BuildConfig.LIBRARY_NAME, BuildConfig.LIBRARY_VERSION));
> ^
> symbol:   variable BuildConfig
> location: class FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar

i guess the reason for my error is related to the used Java-Versions. But i dont know where to optimimize. When i open in android studio the project structure i can see that the generated build.gradle-files for firebase_core etc. mention Java-Version_1_8 (Java 8) as compileoptions. But if i change them to Java_17 there is no change in the behavior. i still get the error "cannot find symbol".

I tried with gradle 7.5 and Gradle 8. Both show the mentioned error.

Another new created flutter project could be run.

My Flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.1, on macOS 14.1.1 23B81 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
```

My build.gradle (project)

```
 buildscript {
     // 202306 BEFORE '1.7.10' AFTER '1.9.21'
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.21'
     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
     }
 
 
  dependencies {
         // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
         // 202306 BEFORE 4.3.10 AFTER 4.4.0
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
     }
 
 }
 
 // 202306 
 subprojects{
     afterEvaluate {
         android {
             namespace 'com.example.camflo'
         }
     } }
 
 allprojects {
     repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
     } }
 
 rootProject.buildDir = '../build' subprojects {
     project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}" } subprojects {
     project.evaluationDependsOn(':app') }
 
 tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

My build.gradle app:

```
 def localProperties = new Properties() def localPropertiesFile =
 rootProject.file('local.properties') if (localPropertiesFile.exists())
 {
     localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
         localProperties.load(reader)
     } }
 
 def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk') if
 (flutterRoot == null) {
     throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.") }
 
 def flutterVersionCode =
 localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode') if
 (flutterVersionCode == null) {
     flutterVersionCode = '1' }
 
 def flutterVersionName =
 localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName') if
 (flutterVersionName == null) {
     flutterVersionName = '1.0' }
 
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' apply from:
 "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
 
 android {
     // compileSdkVersion 28
     compileSdkVersion 33
 
     namespace = "com.example.camflo"
 
     sourceSets {
         main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
     }
 
     // 202306 added buildFeatures and buildConfig with no change of error
     // buildFeatures {
     //    buildConfig = true
     // }
 
     defaultConfig {
         // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
         applicationId "com.camflo.app"
         minSdkVersion 29
         // minSdkVersion 30
         // targetSdkVersion 28
         targetSdkVersion 33
         versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
         versionName flutterVersionName
     }
 
     buildTypes {
         release {
             // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
             // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
             signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
         }
     }
     lint {
         disable 'InvalidPackage'
     } }
 
 flutter {
     source '../..' }
 
 dependencies {
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0' }
```

My dependencies:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <=4.0.0"

dependency_overrides:
  package_info_plus: ^4.2.0
  http: ^1.1.2

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
 
  shared_preferences: "2.2.2"
  platform: ^3.1.3 
  firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_analytics: ^10.7.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.14.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.5.2
  cloud_firestore: ^4.13.2
  provider: ^6.1.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  timeago: ^3.6.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.0
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  uuid: ^4.2.1
  image: ^4.1.3
  animator: ^3.3.0
  http: ^0.13.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.5
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  
  preload_page_view: ^0.2.0
  flutter_google_places_hoc081098: ^1.2.0
  material_design_icons_flutter: 7.0.7296
  google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.20-nullsafety.2
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.4.5
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

  dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Any updates? I have the same problem and try many solutions but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

for 1st try i think error is most likely a mismatch between the flutter and Android versions used in the project. the buildConfig symbol is generated by the Android build system, and if the flutter and android versions are not compatible, the symbol may not be available.
so pleas do the following .

1.run - `flutter upgrade`

2.Update the Android SDK- in android studio go to the SDK Manager, then installing any available updates.

3. Update the build.gradle files in your project to do so

a. inside project-level build.gradle file:

Change the ext.kotlin_version to a compatible version for that you can check the latest Kotlin version on the Kotlin website.

then
Change the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4' to a compatible version. You can check the latest Android Gradle Plugin version on the Android Gradle Plugin Release Notes page.

b. in-side the app-level build.gradle file:

Change the compileSdkVersion to a compatible version. You can check the latest Android SDK version in the Android Studio SDK Manager.

then change the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to compatible versions. Make sure they are within the range supported by your Flutter version.

after going all the above try run the following command to sync the project with the updated configurations

```
flutter pub get
```

hope you use version control in you project .so that you can always rollback

let me know any

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it didnt solve the error. I tried several combinations, older versions too,  but noving helped. As you can see i use the newest dependencies. maybe i need a newer java-version. in android studio gradle is defined with java jdk 1.7,

Comment: did you try it with new java-versions ?

Comment: i tried with Jetbrains runtime version 17.0.7 (default in android studio) and Oracle OpenJDK version 21.0.1. It's the same behavior "cannot find symbol".

Comment: can you try these one more time with `flutter clean
   flutter pub get
   flutter run` and if it still gives the error then you can try deleting the .pub-cache folder in your user directory (in this case it should be , /Users/michael/.pub-cache) and then running `flutter pub get` again to fetch the dependencies

Comment: i did "flutter clean" "flutter pub get" "flutter run" and later i deleted the .pub-cache folder. still the same error "cannot find symbol"

Comment: just for clarification you updated all the necessary dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file to their latest versions, including the firebase_core package?

Comment: yes i updated all dependencies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256243/discussion-between-rainy-sidewalks-and-moo).

Comment: Any other ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: pleas go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305553/error-cannot-find-symbol-when-building-for-android-in-flutter) and try if any of these work mean while i am looking in to it. also try it without ` google_mobile_ads: ^3.1.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0` .

Comment: i only use google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0.

Comment: i guess the reason for my error is related to to the used Java-Versions. But i dont know where to optimimize. When i open in android studio the project structure i can see that the generated build.gradle-files for firebase_core etc. mention Java-Version_1_8 (Java 8) as compileoptions. But if i change them to Java_17 there is no change in the behavior. i still get the error "cannot find symbol"

Answer (score 0):

try removing dependency

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
```

in

```
dependencies {
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0' }
```

check the if imports are correct

open android folder in android studio to identify problem in config files

Comment: i removed the dependency. but still get the error "cannot find symbol"

Comment: i guess the reason for my error is related to to the used Java-Versions. But i dont know where to optimimize. When i open in android studio the project structure i can see that the generated build.gradle-files for firebase_core etc. mention Java-Version_1_8 (Java 8) as compileoptions. But if i change them to Java_17 there is no change in the behavior. i still get the error "cannot find symbol"

Answer (score 0):

make the environment to in your pubspec.yml file

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'
```

then run following commands in your flutter project's root directory:

```
flutter clean
flutter upgrade
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub outdated
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
flutter pub get
```

then check if there are any errors in flutter project, might get new errors due to upgrading packages, you just need to update the code to fix it.

also you will need to update your pods, so run following commands in your flutter project's root directory:

```
cd ios
pod repo update
pod update
pod install
cd..
```

also your project uses firebase so you can config your flutter project with your firebase project using FlutterFire cli once.

here is the link to [FlutterFireCLI Migration Guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration), I know it's archived but it's still relevant till today, it will help to migrate to the new way of using Firebase in Flutter, as you said your project is 2 Years old so you need to migrate.

here is quick overview on how to use FlutterFire CLI, refer to the link I provided above to learn more about how to use it:

```
# install firebase cli if not installed already
npm install -g firebase-tools

# Install the CLI if not already done so
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

# Run the `configure` command, select a Firebase project and platforms
flutterfire configure
```

Open Android Folder of your flutter project in Android Studio then try this:

```
Build -> Clean Project;
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

then try running your Flutter Project.

## **EDIT**

Try running following command in your project's root directory.

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Once you are done with everything, run `flutter clean` one more time and then `flutter run` in your flutter project's root dir.

Comment: I followed the steps but i still get the error "cannot find symbol" for buildconfig. After deleting the .pub-cache-folder i always get errors that i have to delete the package-name in the generated module-manifests. After deleting the package-namens i get the "cannot find symbol" error for BuildConfig of firebase_core

Comment: @Moo Hi try the other steps that I added as EDIT in the answer.

Comment: i did clean project, invalidate caches and rebuild. still the same error "cannot find symbol"

Comment: @Moo Hi, I have edited my answer, can you try that.